# Updating the Upgrade Authority Programmatically

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js

I have utilised the Solana CLI to handle the upgrade authority for my program. However, I now require the ability to update the upgrade authority using JavaScript. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There certainly is! I took a look around, and since I know that the governance program is typically used to upgrade other programs, I found the instruction in its UI code:

```
export async function createSetUpgradeAuthority(
  programId: PublicKey,
  upgradeAuthority: PublicKey,
  newUpgradeAuthority: PublicKey
) {
  const bpfUpgradableLoaderId = BPF_UPGRADE_LOADER_ID

  const [programDataAddress] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [programId.toBuffer()],
    bpfUpgradableLoaderId
  )

  const keys = [
    {
      pubkey: programDataAddress,
      isWritable: true,
      isSigner: false,
    },
    {
      pubkey: upgradeAuthority,
      isWritable: false,
      isSigner: true,
    },
    {
      pubkey: newUpgradeAuthority,
      isWritable: false,
      isSigner: false,
    },
  ]

  return new TransactionInstruction({
    keys,
    programId: bpfUpgradableLoaderId,
    data: Buffer.from([4, 0, 0, 0]), // SetAuthority instruction bincode
  })
}
```

Found at https://github.com/solana-labs/governance-ui/blob/1b4df7486f45ad8c42771c5d4b5877843ffe788a/tools/sdk/bpfUpgradeableLoader/createSetUpgradeAuthority.ts